# Route DNS queries for specific domain

Tags: windows, vpn, dns

Is it possible to configure Windows to direct DNS lookup requests for `<servername>.corporatedomain.com`, to a specific DNS server?

I asked a question recently about routing my DNS off the VPN DNS server for web requests, so now I have the default DNS server on the VPN set to 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4. Even before doing this, though, I was unable to query servers on the VPN by name (e.g. `<servername>`). I'd like to set up the VPN so that when I ask for anything ending `corporatedomain.com` it will look to the DNS servers on the VPN first.

Comment: See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1374119/433287) - seems like you can do it with a single PowerShell command.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer that comes to mind is setting up a DNS server with just a zone entry for corporatedomain.com that holds NS records pointing to the DNS servers of your VPN.
All other requests should be forwarded to the appropriate DNS servers.

Comment: Sorry, I Completely lost sight of this question. I'd rather not have to set up a DNS server as it's not all that portable. Equally, I'd like to be able to give the solution to everyone using the VPN conection. Ideally, I'm looking for a solution that can be done on machine (similar to `route add`) to set it up.