# Use DNS server depending on the top-level domain

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, dns

Is there any way to configure Windows (10 in my case), to use specific DNS server for specific TLDs?

For example I want to use the local DNS server for the `.local`, `.lab`, `.corp` and `.example` domains. But I want to use a public DNS server for any other domain.

I know I could use the public DNS server as a primary, which would fail for the local TLDs and therefore would fallback to the secondary DNS server (the local one). This would work, but it would also leak all the URLs/Domain names to a public DNS server.

**edit:** I know I could use the hosts file to statically map the local URLs, but that's not very viable and I would like to avoid that.

Comment: See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1374119/433287) - seems like you can do it with a single PowerShell command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can only be done on Windows Server using [Conditional Forwarding](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794735(WS.10).aspx).

On a workstation Windows there is no such option. Do you happen to have control over your "local" DNS server? If so, you could configure it to use your public DNS server as an upstream server, i.e. any TLD other than the ones it knows would be forwarded.

Otherwise you could install a DNS server on your workstation and configure it to use your local DNS server for the TLDs listed above and the public DNS for everything else. You could then point Windows to use 127.0.0.1 as your DNS server. [Unbound](https://unbound.net/) seems to be a DNS server that could do that job on Windows (plus it's open source).